# O que significa ":-!!" em linguagem C?

Tags: c, linux

Em uma biblioteca do kernel Linux, especificamente esta: [/usr/include/linux/kernel.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ff2d8b19a3a62559afba1c53360c8577a7697714/include/linux/kernel.h#L677-L682), há uma macro com um código estranho para mim:

```
/* Force a compilation error if condition is true, but also produce a
   result (of value 0 and type size_t), so the expression can be used
   e.g. in a structure initializer (or where-ever else comma expressions
   aren't permitted). */
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL(e) ((void *)sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
```

O que significa ":-!!" em linguagem C?

Comment: - sinal negativo, ! negação lógica. Veja esta resposta no SO.com http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229793/2556111

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O `!!` é um truque antigo para converter valores numéricos em booleanos.

- O primeiro `!` nega o valor, se for `0` vira `1`, se for qualquer outra coisa vira `0`.
- O segundo `!` nega isso novamente

A próxima parte é usar isso na definição de um campo de bits em uma `struct`.

Quando se define um campo numérico inteiro em uma `struct` pode-se dizer quantos bits ele vai ocupar:

```
struct Fields {
    int a: 6; //Ocupa 6 bits
    int b: 2; //Ocupa 2 bits
};
```

E o número de bits não pode ser negativo. Por isso o `-` antes do `!!`: Se `e` for diferente de zero teríamos um campo de bits com tamanho negativo, o que dá erro de compilação. Se `e` for zero teremos um campo de bits de tamanho zero, o que é válido, embora não tenha muita serventia. Mas como aquilo tudo é um conjunto de macros para checar constantes em tempo de compilação acaba sendo útil.

Answer (score 8):

`!!` é a dupla negacao. É um truque usado nalgumas linguagens para converter um resultado para boolean. O primeiro `!` (a contar da direita para a esquerda) nega a expressao `(e)` com um cast implicito para boolean, e o segundo `!` nega novamente.

O `-` é um simples operador matematico de subtração.

Entao, se `e` for falso, é definido um inteiro com 0 de largura `struct{int: 0;}`.
Se `e` for verdadeiro, é definido um inteiro com largura negativa `struct{int: -1;}`, causando um erro de compilacao.

Answer (score 7):

Em uma estrutura bitfield você pode especificar o tamanho em bits de cada membro, mantendo suas características originais. Exemplo:

```c
struct bitfield {
    signed int a : 3; // Um inteiro usando complemento de dois com 3 bits. Entre -4 e 3.
    unsigned b : 4;   // Um inteiro sem sinal. Valores entre 0 e 15.
};
```

E como não há *padding* entre os membros<sup>1</sup> (apenas no final) é comumente usado em interfaces com hardware ou para ler alguns tipos de arquivos.

O detalhe é que a expressão que denota o tamanho de cada membro não é um literal integral, mas sim uma expressão constante que resulta em um integral<sup>2</sup>. Sendo assim o seguinte é válido:

```c
struct bitfield {
    int a : 1+1;
};
```

A regra também afirma que se o tamanho for zero o membro não terá nenhum efeito (efetivamente não existirá) e que esse tamanho não pode ser negativo. Posso então criar uma macro assim:

```c
#define ERROR_IF_NEGATIVE(e) struct { int : e; };
```

Repare a omissão do nome da struct e do membro. Mas é claro, essa macro vai falhar com valores muito grandes (que excedam o tamanho em bits em um int). Podemos melhorar um pouco usando a dupla negação. `!!e` é `0` se `e` for `0` e `1` se `e` for qualquer outro valor. Assim podemos fazer `-!!e` para obter um valor negativo se a condição for verdadeira.

```c
#define ERROR_IF(e) struct { int : -!!e; };
```

Mas repare que essa macro pode ser usada apenas onde definir uma estrutura é válido, mas não no meio de outras expressões. É ai que entra o `sizeof`. Em C o `sizeof` de uma estrutura vazia é sempre `0`<sup>3</sup>:

```c
#define ZERO_UNLESS(e) (sizeof(struct { int : -!!e; }));
```

Agora você pode usar no meio de qualquer expressão. Se a condição for verdadeira você terá um erro de compilação. Caso contrário o resultado será zero.

```c
int a = 4 + ZERO_UNLESS(sizeof(int) > 2);
```

Esse tipo de macro é similar à [`assert`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert), mas a condição deve ser uma expressão constante e será avaliada em tempo de compilação, gerando nenhum custo de performance. A operação é equivalente ao `static_assert` do C++11.

---

1. Um monte de exceções. A maior parte deve ser definido pela implementação. Sessão 6.7.2.1/11:

   > An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.
2. Sessão 6.7.2.1/4:

   > The expression that specifies the width of a bit-field shall be an integer constant expression with a nonnegative value that does not exceed the width of an object of the type that would be specified were the colon and expression omitted. If the value is zero, the declaration shall have no declarator.
3. Não encontrei uma referência para comprovar isso. Parece ser uma extensão do GCC e não um comportamento definido pelo C, não tenho certeza. Já no C++ o `sizeof` de uma estrutura vazia é `1`.