# Significado do operador?

Tags: php, operadores

Qual é a função de por um `!!` num if por exemplo? sei que `!` por si só inverte o valor de um resultado booleano, mas testei o `!!` e nada mudou no resultado, exemplo:

```
$teste = true;
if(!!$teste) {
   echo "é verdade!";
} else {
   echo "é mentira!";
}
```

e resultou em true esse if

Comment: Eu estava publicando a resposta :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O operador `!` nega. Se eu colocar um outro `!` antes, estarei negando a primeira negação.

Ou seja:

Se `i == verdade` e `!i == falsa`, então `!!i == verdade`

Eu poderia ter mais operadores de negação antes.

Ou seja, eu poderia ter isso:

```
$teste = true;
if(!!!!$teste) {
    echo "é verdade!";
} else {
    echo "é mentira!";
}
```

... que funciona numa boa. Eu estaria negando uma negação.

Comment: Isso não explica pra que serve a dupla negação. Aqui você pode ver mais detalhes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29014/qual-o-sentido-de-usar-dupla-nega%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-javascript

Comment: Então não serve para nada, se tirar os `!!` é mesma coisa que não colocar. Certo ?

Comment: @Zoom vide link acima. É uma espécie de "cast".

Comment: !! é o que se chama de `dupla negação`, ou se preferir `double not operator`. Na pratica... para que eu usaria isso? não.. sei. Talvez sirva para fins didácticos

Comment: É só mais uma doideira do php. Você pode fazer isso também `var_dump(!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! false != true)`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters nao é uma doideira, é uma maneira de cast para valor bool.

Comment: @Bacco desde que eu nunca usaria essa expressão, é doideira sim. Se quer fazer um cast, o php já tem um mecanismo para isso: a função `boolval` do php 5.6, ou o operador de cast `(bool)`. Não é necessário usar dupla negação no PHP. Isso é coisa de linguagens como javascript.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters você não usaria, outros usariam. Questão de legibilidade e simplicidade.

Comment: Pra mim é bobeira também. Nem no PHP, nem no Javascript usaria esse paranauê. Quem concorda dá um Like.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters e Zoom não tem nada a ver com a linguagem. É usado em JS, é usado em PHP, e é uma técnica conhecida em várias outras linguagens. Note que o exemplo do OP não é um caso para uso, isso é normalmente usado dentro de expressões mais complexas para forçar a previsibilidade do resultado sem deixar o código todo rebuscado. Se não querem usar, é só não usar. Outros usam. Assim como somar zero em string, para obter sempre numérico. Cast explícito e implícito são coisas normais.

Comment: @Bacco, Defensor dos Operadores Lógicos do PHP. Brincadeira... Mas o bom de algumas linguagens é isso, várias maneiras de realizar diversas funções. Mas assim, quando desenvolvo algo, tento ao máximo evitar conversões.

Comment: @Zoom nao tou defendendo não, dá pra usar mal também (a pergunta tem um exemplo de péssimo uso). É que do jeito que vcs falaram, um leitor que desconhece a utilidade pode achar que não serve pra nada, só por isso comentei. Assim ao menos algum curioso vai ter que pesquisar mais, e não saír repetindo o que leu (nem de vcs nem de mim) kkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, outro exemplo => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4018/91

Comment: @WallaceMaxters quer um exemplo simples de que pode ser útil : `$arrayPopulado = !!array()`;

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert `$arrayPopulado  = (bool) array()`